# 2x1 faceting with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a simple facet with histograms in ggplot2

```
data <- read.csv("/hist_distances.csv", check.names = FALSE, sep = ",")

mdata <- melt(data)

m <- ggplot(data, aes(x=Distance))
m + geom_histogram()
```

> head(data)

Gives:

```
     Times Distance
1 3.093060 260.8840
2 2.557780 187.4960
3 0.263611  10.6584
4 2.880000 184.5970
5 5.035000 281.3490
6 6.952780 251.4730
```

> head(mdata)

gives:

```
  variable    value
1    Times 3.093060
2    Times 2.557780
3    Times 0.263611
4    Times 2.880000
5    Times 5.035000
6    Times 6.952780
```

and

> tail(mdata)

gives:

```
     variable    value
1739 Distance 1.103670
1740 Distance 1.695610
1741 Distance 3.795020
1742 Distance 6.651960
1743 Distance 0.719843
1744 Distance 6.504050
```

This produces this graphic:
[image]

I have tried:

```
m <- ggplot(mdata, aes(x=value)) +
geom_histogram() +
m + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

With no success.

How can I produce a facetted graph instead, with a histogram of variable "times" at the top and a histogram of variable "distances" at the bottom?

Comment: Have you seen [facet_wrap](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html)? Try `facet_wrap(~variable)` in your case.

Comment: Oops, yes, I updated the question

Comment: Does `facet_wrap(~variable)` not work for you since it produces a 1x2 rather than a 2x1 plot? Using `facet_grid(variable~.)` instead of `facet_wrap` produces a 2x1 plot.

Comment: You need to change `data` to `mdata` in your last invocation of `gglot` so that `ggplot` will use the `mdata` data frame.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I wrote too fast...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `facet_grid(variable ~ .)`, where facet_grid(row ~ column):

```
df <- data.frame(Time = rnorm(100),
                 Distance = rnorm(100)
                )
dfm <- melt(df)

ggplot(dfm, aes(x=value)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(variable ~ .)
```

Edit for follow-up comment:
If your data are on different scales, use `facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free")`.

See `help(facet_grid)` for options.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! Now my data range is different from one variable to the other. Distance ranges from 0 to 600 and times from 0 to 10. Is there a way to adjust x scales? Please let me know if you'd rather have me ask another question. Cheers!

Comment: Use `facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_x")`. If you want plots in one column, use  `facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_x", ncol=1)`, for  side-by-side, use  `facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_x", ncol=2)`.